# VBA Dictionary.Exists Method Returning False Negative Given String From String Array

Tags: excel, vba

I am passing a key of type string, located in a string array, into a scripting.dictionary.exists(key) method which is returning a false negative.  I would like it to correctly return a positive Boolean value so I can determine whether the key is valid per a business process.  The valid values are stored in the dictionary.

I've checked to ensure that the compare mode of the dictionary is TextCompare which wouldn't have mattered because it turns out that the case of the string in both the dictionary and array are identical.  I've also ensured that the variable types are both string (8).  Additionally, I've made sure that the string in the string array and dictionary are identical.  Lastly, I checked to make sure that the method would also return a false positive if string was entered directly into argument instead of being passed to argument through a reference via the array.

```
Function fvalidatedata(saInput() As String) As String()

    Dim dInvalidRecords As Scripting.Dictionary, _
        dValidDisputeStatuses As Scripting.Dictionary, dDisputeStatusErrorMap As Scripting.Dictionary, _
        dValidReasonCodes As Scripting.Dictionary, dReasonCodeAbbrevMap As Scripting.Dictionary, _
        saListBoxValues() As String, i As Long, ii As Long, frmIRC As New ufInvalidReasonCode

    Set dInvalidRecords = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dValidDisputeStatuses = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dDisputeStatusErrorMap = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dValidReasonCodes = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dReasonCodeAbbrevMap = New Scripting.Dictionary

    dInvalidRecords.CompareMode = BinaryCompare
    dValidDisputeStatuses.CompareMode = TextCompare
    dDisputeStatusErrorMap.CompareMode = TextCompare
    dValidReasonCodes.CompareMode = BinaryCompare
    dReasonCodeAbbrevMap.CompareMode = BinaryCompare

    Set dValidDisputeStatuses = fValidDisputeStatusMap
    Set dDisputeStatusErrorMap = fDisputeStatusErrorMap
    Set dValidReasonCodes = fValidReasonCodes
    Set dReasonCodeAbbrevMap = fReasonCodeAbbrevMap

    For i = 2 To UBound(saInput, 1)
        'Dispute Status Validation
            If Not dValidDisputeStatuses.Exists(saInput(i, 12)) Then
                Debug.Print dValidDisputeStatuses.Exists(saInput(i, 12))
                If dDisputeStatusErrorMap.Exists(saInput(i, 12)) Then
                    saInput(i, 12) = dDisputeStatusErrorMap(saInput(i, 12))
                Else
                    ReDim saListBoxValues(0 To dValidDisputeStatuses.Count - 1)
                    For ii = 0 To dValidDisputeStatuses.Count - 1
                        saListBoxValues(ii) = dValidDisputeStatuses.Keys(ii)
                    Next ii
                    frmIRC.ListBox1.List = saListBoxValues
                    frmIRC.l1 = "Please select valid dispute status from the list below for record " & saInput(i, 3) & " and submit once complete."
                    frmIRC.Show vbModeless

                End If
            End If
        'Reason Code Validation
    Next i

End Function
Function fValidDisputeStatusMap() As Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim dMap As Scripting.Dictionary, lo As ListObject, i As Long

    Set dMap = New Scripting.Dictionary
    dMap.CompareMode = TextCompare

    Set lo = Application.Workbooks("RnR_Dispute_Process_Workbook.xlsx").Sheets("Update Dictionary").ListObjects("Valid_Statuses")

    For i = 1 To lo.ListColumns("Valid Statuses").DataBodyRange.Count
        If Not dMap.Exists(lo.ListColumns("Valid Statuses").DataBodyRange(i)) Then
            dMap.Add lo.ListColumns("Valid Statuses").DataBodyRange(i), vbNullString
        End If
    Next i

    Set fValidDisputeStatusMap = dMap

    Set dMap = Nothing

End Function
```

I expect that the output of (Not dValidDisputeStatuses.Exists(saInput(i, 12))) to be TRUE if saInput(i,12) does not exist in the dictionary, but it does.

Comment: Good work on solving your own question! If you'd like to better understand *why*, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am passing a key of type string

But you're not :) You're actually passing a `Range` object here:

```
If Not dMap.Exists(lo.ListColumns("Valid Statuses").DataBodyRange(i))
```

It happens to be the case that *most* of the time (e.g., on assignment *to* a Range) the `Range` object will return its default property (`Cells`) which returns its default property (`Value`) but when *getting* a Range, that's not so reliable.

You've stumbled upon an interesting case! While the `Keys` in a dictionary can by *anything* except an array, as you've unwittingly observed, strange things may appear to happen when you use complex objects as `Keys`.

> A `Dictionary` object is the equivalent of a PERL associative array. Items, which can be any form of data, are stored in the array. Each item is associated with a unique key. The key is used to retrieve an individual item and is usually an integer or a string, but can be anything except an array.

Here's the quirk: Each time you reference a `Range` object, it's given a different memory location. You can verify this quite easily:

```
Dim i as Long
Dim r as Range
For i = 1 to 3
    Set r = Range("A1")
    Debug.Print(ObjPtr(r))
Next
```

What this means in your case is that the `Exists` method will *apparently* fail (i.e., returns `False` when it seemingly should return `True`), for example, expanding on the above:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim r As Range
Dim d as Object
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For i = 1 to 3
    Set r = Range("A1")
    d.Add r, i
Next
```

That will produce a dictionary with 3 unique keys, which are all pointers to the *same* `Range` object!

If instead, the `Set` assignment is *outside* the loop, it will fail as expected on the second iteration, because it's now attempting to add a pointer which already exists in the dictionary.

```
Set r = Range("A1")
For i = 1 to 3
    d.Add r, i
Next
```

The moral of this story is: use caution when assigning `Object` types as `Keys` in a `Dictionary`.

## Can we use `Object` types as `Dictionary.Keys`?

Yes, but it seems to be a more complicated implementation. There may be other ways, but one obvious (at least to me) solution is to build the keys as an array or collection first, and then iterate over that list while testing `Dictionary.Exists`.

```
Sub foo2()

Dim d As Dictionary
Dim r As Range, w As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim keys(1 To 3) As Range
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Set r = Range("A1:A3")
' Create our keys in one place
For i = 1 To r.Cells.Count
    Set keys(i) = r.Cells(i)
Next

' Iterate the KEYS rather than the range
For i = LBound(keys) To UBound(keys)
    d.Add keys(i), i
Next
Debug.Print "The dictionary initially contains " & d.Count & " keys."
'If we test Exist against our keys array, results are as expected:
For i = LBound(keys) To UBound(keys)
    If Not d.Exists(keys(i)) Then
        d.Add r.Cells(i), i
    End If
Next
Debug.Print "The dictionary still contains " & d.Count & " keys."

' Iterate the RANGE now and no error occurs!
For i = 1 To r.Cells.Count
    If Not d.Exists(r.Cells(i)) Then
        d.Add r.Cells(i), i
    End If
Next
' But, our dictionary now has 6 keys, instead of 3!!!
Debug.Print "The dictionary now contains " & d.Count & " keys!"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:

```
For i = 1 To lo.ListColumns("Valid Statuses").DataBodyRange.Count
    If Not dMap.Exists(lo.ListColumns("Valid Statuses").DataBodyRange(i)) Then
        dMap.Add lo.ListColumns("Valid Statuses").DataBodyRange(i), vbNullString
    End If
Next i
```

should have been

```
For i = 1 To lo.ListColumns("Valid Statuses").DataBodyRange.Count
    If Not dMap.Exists(lo.ListColumns("Valid Statuses").DataBodyRange(i).value2) Then
        dMap.Add lo.ListColumns("Valid Statuses").DataBodyRange(i).value2, vbNullString
    End If
Next i
```

I was referencing a range instead of a value.  Apparently vartype() tests the value inside of a range given a range value.